# Change the underscore to input area in HTML

Tags: html, css

```
<P class="p3"><FONT class="ft4">Full Names as in Passport /NRIC_____________________________________________________________________</FONT></P>
```

As you can see, this is part of an HTML form.  I want the long underscore to change to a text input area with the same length and as user types I want to display the words above.  Please kindly help me, thanks.  I have tried and havent gotten very far.

Comment: i have tried to use <textarea style="border: 0px solid #000000;">blah</textarea> but it just creates an invisible textfield

Comment: don't use `<FONT>` tags. That's soooo 1996!

Comment: haha that is so specific @SeanPatrickFloyd usually people refer to the late 90's u specifically mentioned 1996.. so what do u suggest that i use?

Comment: @BharathPriya a) the reason I say 1996 is because I started with HTML in 96 and that was what it was like then b) the question is tagged CSS, isn't it? Use CSS! You are using CSS classes anyway apparently, but don't use deprecated tags, use e.g. `<span>` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="text" style="border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
input.user_input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

input.user_input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #666;
  outline-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My form</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="form_action.php" method="get">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>My form</legend>
        <label>First name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" class="user_input" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </fieldset>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```